# Conditional Grouping in RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am able to conditionally group by a certain item in RDLC, but I'd also like the option to not group by anything. I'm not sure on how to do that.

Here's my current Group By expression:

```
<Group Name="GroupBy">
    <GroupExpressions>
      <GroupExpression>=iif(Parameters!GroupBy.Value = "C", Fields!City.Value, Fields!State.Value)</GroupExpression>
    </GroupExpressions>
</Group>
```

I have three group by options that I'd like:

If the value is "C", then group by City

If the value is "S", then group by State

If the value is "N", then don't group by anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this statement and if it doesn't = C or S then group by some unique ID value.

```
=iif(Parameters!GroupBy.Value = "C", Fields!City.Value, iif(Parameters!GroupBy.Value = "S", Fields!State.Value, Fields!SomeUniqueValueUniqueToAllRecords.Value))
```

Hope that helps.